# I want to number to string for imread directory

Tags: python

file name is D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\objects\object (2).png

and there are many files like object (3).png, object (4).png, object (5).png ...

so i want to read this file, then i tried

```
i = 2
org_img = cv2.imread(r'D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\objects\object (' str(i) ').png') # original image
```

and

```
i = 2
org_img = cv2.imread(r'D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\objects\object (%s).png') %i # original image
```

but failed.

In matlab, it is easy to run like this,

```
i = 2
org_img = imread('D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\objects\object (' num2str(i) ').png')
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, try using `+` sign:

```
i = 2
org_img = cv2.imread(r'D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\objects\object (' + str(i) + ').png') # original image
```

And formatting this way:

```
i = 2
org_img = cv2.imread(r'D:\remedi\Exercise\Xray\objects\object (%s).png' % i) # original image
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you very very much! By any chance, can i ask why using + +?

Comment: @BBoDDo That's used for adding the strings up, so "something plus something" get it?

Comment: @BBoDDo Since you got 15 repuation may you up-vote?